# Authentication, Authorisation & User Tracking without Sessions

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Using Java Web applications (JSP/Servlets, no EJBs), what is the best approach for authenticating a user and authorising their actions, without utilising `HttpSession`'s ?

**NB** The reason for this approach/question is that I wish our applications to remain stateless, so I do not need to replicate full sessions within the *geographically dispersed* data centers, and can more easily add and remove servers from the cluster.

Thanks

Comment: Basic Auth (via HTTPS)? OAuth?

Comment: Both good ideas (i hadn't considered Basic Auth at all). OAuth might be a good way to go, however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the token after successfull logon and on each request verify only this token. The token, of course, need to be replicated, but it should not exceed 100 bytes of data, so comparing to 'heavy' weight of typical `HttpSession`, the performance impact would be quite low.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as the accepted, as it provides the closest match to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Public Key Infrastructure. Create your own CA, sign and hand out user certificates. Enable client-auth on your sever.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about this approach? I'm intrigued, but not sure how our application would go about a) handing out certs to each user that registers, b) authenticates based on the cert, c) ensuring a reasonable level of security when on a shared computer. Thx

Comment: Oh, also, our site runs under both HTTP and HTTPS, so can this approach still be considered?

Comment: This only works on HTTPS, so maybe it's not a good approach for you. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Hidden form field" or "URL rewriting"

Comment: what should be put into the "hidden form field"? Not all our pages contain forms.